# If $A$ is nilpotent and $AB = A$, does $B$ have to be identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

I have seen posts asking under what conditions does $B$ have to be the identity matrix if $AB = A$, but none of them could answer my question. I know that if $A$ is singular, then $A = AB$ doesn't necessarily imply $B = I$. A counter-example would be $A$ being a idempotent matrix (then $B = A$). What if $A$ is nilpotent (so $A$ cannot be idempotent) and nonzero? In that case, can I claim that $B = I$?

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you. I modified my question.

Comment: Let $B=I+xy^T$ where $x\in\ker(A)$ and $y\ne0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is nilpotent, $A$ must have $0$ as its eigenvalue, so it is singular.

This means that your second assumption is actually same with your first assumption.

**Append :**

For these two matrices $A, B$ such that

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then you can check that $A$ is not idempotent (In fact, $A$ is nilpotent).

And you can also check that $AB=A$. But $B\neq I$.

Comment: Right, but can you give me an example where $AB = A$, $B \neq I$, and $A$ is not idempotent? Here, I'm adding in a restriction that $A$ cannot be idempotent.

Comment: @user1691278 I appended an example what you need

Answer (score 3):

How about
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} & B &= \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then $A$ is nilpotent and not idempotent, $B$ is not the identity, and $AB=A$.

(The inspiration here was the structure of the Lie algebra $\mathrm{sl}(2)$, i.e., the traceless 2x2 matrices.)

Comment: Sorry, @bFur4list answered first, but I like your answer too.

Comment: @user1691278 They added their examples a minute after I answered, but that's ok.